# BlackBerry API Compatibility Testing

Tags: api, testing, blackberry, version, compatibility

Is there an easy way to find out the minimum BlackBerry API version required by an application? I know there are several ways, but I think there must be something really simple that is too obvious for me to think of. One way would be to download all device simulators provided by RIM and test the application on each of them. Another way could be to look up all classes and methods used in the application in the API reference and see in which API version they were introduced. The last way would be to pay a testing company (RIM has links to some them on their developer site). Is there something else I didn't think of? Something simple, free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download all the old JDE's, start with the lowest you can find and see if your project compiles, if not try a version higher.

Comment: Does that mean the that all later versions after the first working one are compatible too?

Comment: yes all devices are backwards compatible, there might be usability issues on the Storm due to its touchscreeen interface though.

Comment: That takes care of most things, but not all things. For instance, 5.0 has functions for virtual keyboard, but can not instantiate an instance. Thus, 6.0 phones can hide bugs which will appear in 5.0. I am sure there are other examples. Also, those old JDEs only work on Windows.